# Pull from Oracle sequence with Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I've a sequence defined in my Oracle database. 
Can I pull from this sequence using Hibernate? I don't want to use the sequence for generating ids for my objects, so `@GeneratedValue` and `@Id` are not the things I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  <sql-query name="sequenceValue">  
     <return alias="mySeq" class="MySequences"/>  
       select my_schema.seq_myid.nextval as mySeq from dual  
  </sql-query>
```

Comment: How do we do it from hbm file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
select my_schema.seq_myid.nextval from dual;
```

This will return a one record result set with the next value in your sequence.  You can then use

```
select my_schema.seq_myid.currval from dual;
```

To get the current value of the sequence.

Comment: The key issue of my question is "...using Hibernate".

Comment: I understand, but I don't believe Hibernate explicitly does what you're asking to do.  Therefore, you execute the query (using Hibernate) and you receive the data you're looking for.