# Get from oracle sequence with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am working with hibernate, and a oracle 10 db. I need to get the next sequence value from a table, and want to know how. 
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428854/pull-from-oracle-sequence-with-hibernate) article, and asking: is there a better way the get the value, without defining a query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Getting the next (`nextval`) or current (`currval`) value from a sequence is typically done using a select. Even in PLSQL, SELECT INTO is used, like this:

```
SELECT YourSequence.NextVal INTO :new.ID FROM DUAL;
```

Simple assignment like this won't work:

```
:new.ID := YourSeqence.NextVal;
```

Comment: So there is no way of doing this in hibernate?

Comment: I have question here if you have some inputs then it would be really helpful...http://stackoverflow.com/q/11313854/164299

Comment: Sounds like the same question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but is there a way to do this in `hbm` file?

Comment: @GolezTrol can you explain this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id and what are those annotations for? I thought that was an alternative

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap) is useful. It's not exactly the same, but the question and answers show how to use sequences with hibernate. I can't help you further. I don't use hibernate in my daily work, and this questions was asked almost 5 years ago.