# hibernate postgres id incrementing in 10s

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting a problem using hibernate with postgresql

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

the problem is the id is generating in 10s eg

```
10
20
30
```

How do I make it

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: What is your sequence's increment step? Isn't it 10?

Answer (score 0):

[See hibernate allocationSize](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier)

Also see this - [hibernate oracle sequence produces large gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, you shall use another annotation @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator
Here is how I did

```
@Id
@javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "order_id_sequence", sequenceName = "order_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "order_id_sequence")
@Column(name = "id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, you won't be able to rely on values from sequences not having gaps, as the database can't roll back the sequence in situations like:

1. Session A pulls a number, say 1, from the sequence.
2. Session B pulls a number, 2, from the sequence.
3. Session A rolls back its transaction.
4. Session B commits.

So, I would advise you to either not worry about it or use a different method for producing a series of unique numbers without gaps.