# Hibernate throws PK violation error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

I've been using hibernate with jboss 4.2.3 and everything was working, now i migrated the code to Jboss 7.1.1 and suddenly i start getting :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (OBLICORE.PK_ACE_WORKERS_QUEUE_STATS_ID) violated
```

Also the generated ID's are negative.

The entity that fails is defined as such:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ACE_WORKERS_QUEUE_STATS_ID", sequenceName = "SEQ_ACE_WORKERS_QUEUE_STATS_ID", allocationSize = 500)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ACE_WORKERS_QUEUE_STATS_ID")
@Column(name = "ID")
private long Id;
```

I checked the sequence in Oracle and it seems O.K (Like i said, it worked before with jboss 4.2 and nothing changed on the DB side since the migration).

I tried writing Hibernate query logs but couldn't locate that query and I've also logged the specific call that persist this class and saw that it only get called once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this question: [hibernate oracle sequence produces large gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap)

It must be Hibernate's sequence generator which is defaulting to the Hi/Lo algorithm, and the returned values overflowing. You can try using a hibernate-specific annotation to default to the older behaviour `GenericGenerator(name="blah", strategy="sequence")`, or set `allocationSize=1`.

If you are relying on your sequence incrementing by some value larger than 1, you'll have to use a different generator. Or maybe it's enough to set `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` to `false`, but that is in the scope of a new question.

Comment: Thanks you so much, I banged my head on this for so long.

Comment: allocationSize=1 doesn't work for me but  strategy="sequence" works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

When we changed Hibernate to use the new generator, I used the following script to fix the sequences:

```
  DECLARE
    v NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN (select sequence_name from user_sequences) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| r.sequence_name ||' INCREMENT BY 50';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '|| r.sequence_name ||' .NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO v;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```

If your allocationSize is 500, you should change the "INCREMENT BY 50" to "INCREMENT BY 500".

Answer (score 0):

If the generated value of id is not so critical in your project try to use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`
this strategy will generate id avtomatically by incrementing last by one. Hope it will useful for you.

Comment: I have a very big project with many files that use sequences and the product is already deployed at many customers sites (this is version 8), so I'm not free to make changes as I please, i have to stick with what I've got.