# Generated sequence starts with 1 instead of 1000 which is set in annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I would like to ask some help regarding database sequence created by Hibernate.

I have this annotation - the code below - in my entity class in order to have individual sequence for partners table. I expect that the sequence starts with 1000, because I insert test data into my database using import.sql during deploy and I would like to avoid the constraint violation. But when I want to persist data than I got the constraint violation exception and it informs me about the fact the partner_id = 2 already exists. It looks like I missed something.

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(initialValue=1000, 
                        allocationSize=1,
                        name = "partner_sequence", 
                        sequenceName="partner_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="partner_sequence")
    private Long partnerId;
```

The generated sequence looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE partner_sequence
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE partner_sequence
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I use postgres 9.1.

Did I miss something? This is the way how can I approach what I want?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: If you are inserting data through insert script you should avoid the id field insertion so that sequence will get incremented else increment it once you finished after inserting the records.

Comment: The table does not use the sequence generated by hibernate. The table looks like this:
`CREATE TABLE partners
(
  partner_id bigint NOT NULL,
...);`

If I create one from scratch than looks like this:

`CREATE TABLE partners2
(
  partner_id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255)[]
)`

At the first one the datatype is **bigint** and in the second one the datatype is **serial**. Can I configure somehow the generating process to create table like the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialValue` and `alocattionSize` are specific to `hilo` algorithm that uses sequence. According to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier) `initialValue` is not even supported. I don't even see how it could be supported from Java layer since sequence values are generated in the database.

Also see [hibernate oracle sequence produces large gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. You are right, the documentation does not have anything about @initialValue. It looks like I have to manage the test data insertions in a different way. On the other hand, I have to find a way to manage the stored procedures install during deploy. I think test data insertion will be part of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

`initialValue` is supported if `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true` is specified according to [this article](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#ann-setup-properties). I had the same problem as stated in this post, and I solved it following this recipe. Sequences are generated correctly now.

Comment: Even with Hibernate 4.3.6 that supposedly implements JPA 2.1.