# JPA Eclipselink getting wrong sequence number

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, sequence

I'm using some Entities mapped to Oracle DB-Tables. For ID-Generation I'm using a sequence generator annotated as following:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_RULES", sequenceName = "SEQUENZ_RULES")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_RULES")
@Column(name = "SERIALNO")
protected Long serialno;
```

During programm execution I make a new Instance from my Entity and want to persist this generated one. After restart of the database I'm getting wrong sequence numbers through JPA-EclipseLink, but not through the Console directly on the database.

I turned on following properties in the persistence.xml toget also the binding parameters used in the generated statements.

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

For example: If I generate a new instance of my entity and want to persist this one I get 2717 for serialNo and if I execute

```
SELECT SEQUENZ_RULES.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

I get 2767 as nextval. The problem is that the JPA-generated serialNo must be unique, and now I stil have some datasets with this serialNo. Im getting an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (JASON.SYS_C0084866) violated
```

Non Is there any caching through eclipse which is affecting the Sequence Generation or what could be the error for this?

*Used Components:

GlassFish 3.1.1

EclipseLink 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504

Database: Oracle  Version: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit

Driver: Oracle JDBC driver  Version: 11.2.0.1.0*

Answer (score 9):

When you created the sequence you specified a size to increment by.  For example this sequence increments by 1.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE supplier_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

When using the `SequenceGenerator` annotation in JPA you can specify an allocation size.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_RULES", sequenceName = "SEQUENZ_RULES",
    allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_RULES")
@Column(name = "SERIALNO")
protected Long serialno;
```

Make sure the allocation size and the increment match between JPA and the Sequence DDL.

Comment: I don't think that this is the cause here - EclipseLink verifies that allocationSize and INCREMENT BY matches and will throw an exception which explicitly states that if this is not case

Comment: There is an error in your example, allocationSize should be on SequenceGenerator not on GeneratedValue

Comment: @bjartek Thanks, Example has been fixed.

Comment: I used the same, but still I am getting an increment of 2 in Id instead of 1. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change allocationSize=**1** by allocationSize=**2**, it is a Eclipselink bug.