# Change Hibernate sequence generation for existing data

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, sequence

I recently came across [this behavior of Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap) when trying to move from identity column to sequence based id generation for our business entities. The problem is that we have been using `hibernate_sequence` generation on Oracle since the first deployment of our application.

So the question is: is it safe to set the following Hibernate's parameter to `true` on an existing production database without messing up the already generated ids?

```
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
```

EDIT: 
The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e855) describes that the change is not backwards compatible with existing databases.

We are using `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL` in database migrations and this is clearly not at all safe to do, since the `NEXTVAL` might conflict with a pre-existing id.

If I am not terribly wrong, backwards compatibility could be gained by setting the `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE`'s current value to the maximum id in the database. Am I correct? Is there any way to find this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate to hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true, you have to do two things:

1. Set the increment by of the database sequences to the same value as the allocationSize in Hibernate. The default allocationSize is 50.
2. After setting hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true Hibernate will produce values starting with SEQ.NEXTVAL-allocationSize. So you have to increment the sequence with allocation size. That means selecting a SEQ.NEXTVAL.

Here is the Oracle PL/SQL script I was running before the migration:

```
  DECLARE
    v NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN (select sequence_name from user_sequences) LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| r.sequence_name ||' INCREMENT BY 50';
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '|| r.sequence_name ||' .NEXTVAL FROM DUAL' INTO v;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```