# Hibernate and Oracle Sequence

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a problem with Oracle sequence and Hibernate. I used this code to get Oracle Sequence with hibernate

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "student_id_seq", sequenceName = "Student_seq")
@Column(name = "StudentID")
public Long getStudentId() {
    return this.studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}
```

but when i insert a new value to the table, the generated value is incorrect. For example:
when I had two records in database with id 2 and 3, and when I inserted new one, it's id was not 4 but 25. I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Use 'strategy = GenerationType.AUTO' instead of 'strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE'.

Comment: why to do that? (by the way I have allready tried it but no luck)

Answer (score 5):

You should set `allocationSize` to `1`

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "student_id_seq", 
                   sequenceName = "Student_seq",
                   allocationSize = 1)
```

You can read more in documentation [SequenceGenerator doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html)

Answer (score 3):

When I see your question, I wonder : Do you really need to have the id 4 instead of 25, or is it just a technical primary key?
Behind the cache issue, if you ask a value from your sequence (id=4), and then rollback your transaction, the next time you'll ask a number you will have a gap (id=5), behind any hibernate or cache-related issue.

As stated in Przemyslaw's second link, [Sequence gaps - Oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441) : 
"You should never count on a sequence generating anything even close to a gap free sequence of numbers.  They are a high speed, extremely scalable multi-user way to generate surrogate keys for a table."

If, as I understand, there is no need to have contiguous value in your application, the good answer to the "what to do with it" question is : nothing, just live with those gaps.

Comment: Yes: there are ways how to guarantee contiguous IDs on Oracle level(with sequences). It *only* limitation is: "It won't scale at all". One transaction has to wait for the other to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that probably your sequence has a CACHE value specified during its creation. This has been asked a few times already, please check the two following links:

[Sequence gaps in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap/16713095#16713095)

[Sequence gaps - Oracle](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441)

Answer (score 0):

you should create in your database the sequence like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "Student_seq"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 1000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 500 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

and in your `student.hbm.xml` configuration make :

```
<class name="StudentPersistant" table="Student">

<id  name="id"  type="java.lang.Long" column="StudentID" >
      <generator class="sequence"> 
           <param name="sequence">Student_seq</param>   
      </generator>
</id>
```