# Performance issue with hibernate insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am new to hibernate. Please correct me if any of the below is wrong.

There is an entity which is using a sequencegenerator for id generation. Because of this every insert is having two calls one to get sequence and other to do the insert

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="i_gen", sequenceName="b_seq", allocationSize=6)
@GeneratedValue(generator="i_gen")
private Long id;
```

During my research about allocationsize i understood that on specifying the allocation size, we will not call db for next few allocatedsize but simply increment by 1. But i don't see this behavior. Please correct me if i am wrong.

The following are the sql logs that i see

```
[INFO ] [26082016.002159] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 69 msec}
[INFO ] [26082016.002200] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 174 msec}
[INFO ] [26082016.002200] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 74 msec}
[INFO ] [26082016.002200] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 77 msec}
[INFO ] [26082016.002200] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 78 msec}
[INFO ] [26082016.002200] sqltiming:357  - select b_seq.nextval from dual  {executed in 161 msec}
```

For 6 objects insert in a single transaction, i see 6 calls to db to get nextval and 6 inserts. I optimized the inserts by using batch inserts. However i am unable to get around the seq generator issue. I see a huge performance hit because of this.

Is there anything else for this not to make so many db calls for getting seqnumber?

Comment: I cant remember the syntax but you can bulk preallocate a block of primary keys to a JVM then use them

Comment: Your expectation is correct. Other JPA impls that I've used don't call the sequence for each insert, instead using the allocation and caching those. I would normally expect the `@SequenceGenerator` to be specified at CLASS level (though not essential), and see strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE on the `@GeneratedValue` (more essential)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set your DB sequence to `INCREMENT BY 6`. 
As described [here](http://royontechnology.blogspot.rs/2010/04/note-on-allocationsize-parameter-of.html) The allocationSize=n means: "Go and fetch the next value from the database once in every n persist calls. And locally increment the value by 1 in between.". Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36816797/3535298) on SO.