# autogenerate sequence in hibaernate

Tags: java, hibernate

> i have 2000 record in my DB . after inserting a new record the sequnce  start from 1 instead of 2001. In my hibernate POJO i have this following

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_USER_MASTER_ID", sequenceName = "SEQ_USER_MASTER_ID", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_USER_MASTER_ID")
private Long id;
```

> what i need to do in hibernate java to automatically start from 2001 or what ever the max id in table . the sequence should start greater than it . i am struck on this .

Comment: Can you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap)

Comment: [SequenceGenerator.initialValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#initialValue()) ?

Comment: What kind of database do you use?