# Hibernate: How to get current value and next value of database sequence in hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am accessing oracle sequence using hibernate like

```
<id name="id"
        column="ID"
        type="long"
        unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">ID_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

Now let's say if I want to find current value of the sequence or next value from the sequence, how can i do that using hibernate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get from oracle sequence with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843490/get-from-oracle-sequence-with-hibernate)

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386888/get-next-sequence-value-from-database-using-hibernate

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171626/hibernate-with-oracle-sequence-doesnt-use-it

Comment: Oh wait, it seems you can! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346147/hibernate-oracle-sequence-produces-large-gap

Comment: B.t.w., those are the first 4 hits on Google for `hybernate oracle get sequence`