# Get CURRVAL from Oracle sequence in a Hibernate mapping generator

Tags: java, hibernate

im trying to get the currval from a sequence, this is what i have:

Please notice, that im already calling `SEQUENCE.nextval` before the `SEQUENCE.currval` in the same Hibernate session

Hibernate Mapping File:

```
    <id column="SYSTEM_VERSION_ID" name="systemVersionId">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_SYSTEM_VERSIONS</param>
            <param name="value_column">curr_val</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

I thought **`curr_val or currval` as *`value_column`*** will do the trick but no, it keeps performing `nextval` and `printing: Hibernate: select SEQ_SYSTEM_VERSIONS.nextval` from `dual`.

Comment: there are many similar questions on SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843490/get-from-oracle-sequence-with-hibernate

Comment: @harsh , Victor's question is looking for an answer of how to get CURRENT sequence value and link you shared  describes how to get NEXT sequence value. Please consider removing the link or change wordings of your post accordingly.

Comment: I need CURRVAL, please dont post NEXTVAL thanks @DarkKnight

Comment: @DarkKnight The link states that `Getting the next (nextval) or current (currval) value from a sequence is typically done using a select.`, I think the approach described in this would help in Victor's question. Another similar approach @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210273/how-to-retrieve-the-current-value-of-an-oracle-sequence-without-increment-it

Comment: @harsh thanks for updating with new link.

Comment: I think that helps but im trying to find out if it exists a way to do this in my generator